# Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError :No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, django, heroku, importerror

I am trying to deploy a Django program to Heroku. The application runs successfully on my local machine, which uses Anaconda and Python 3.5. I cannot get it to push to Heroku. Upon the command

```
>git push heroku master

remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.8
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.2
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (958efe)…
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to [redacted].
```

I'm not sure why I can't get the `requests` module to be `pip` installed in Heroku. It is in my `requirements.txt` file:

```
Django==2.1.7
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
gunicorn==19.9.0
Unipath==1.1
python-decouple==3.1
Pillow==3.3.0
Markdown==3.0.1
bleach==3.1.0
psycopg2==2.7.7
whitenoise==4.1.2
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
```

Answer (score 6):

The output from your Heroku build shows that you have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` in addition to your `requirements.txt`.

You need to choose between using `pip` (using `requirements.txt`) or Pipenv (using `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`). If all three files are present, Heroku will install with Pipenv, ignoring your `requirements.txt` file.

Either

- move your requirements to your `Pipfile` and run Pipenv locally to install them and update your `Pipfile.lock`, delete your `requirements.txt`, commit, and push (to use Pipenv), or
- delete the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, use `pip` (or `pip-tools` or similar) locally, commit, and push (to use `pip`).

Comment: Thank you, how do I delete pipenv? The Pipfile and Pipfile.lock dont appear to be files in my directory.

Comment: You don't have those files locally? Are you 100% sure about that? What tools are you using locally for virtual environments and dependency management?

Comment: @emericaism, are you still having trouble with this? Did you get it working?

Comment: @Chris Hey Chris, I'm having similar issue, do you mind taking a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336072/heroku-modulenotfounderror-even-though-it-clearly-exists