# Heroku ModuleNotFoundError even though it clearly exists

Tags: python, heroku, flask

My file structure looks like this:

```
   .
    ├── AirQualityVisualzationApp
    │      ├──./static
    │      ├──./templates
    |      ├──./air_quality_api.py
    │      ├── ./app.py
    ├── ./nltk.txt
    │
    ├── ./Procfile
    │
    ├── ./requirements.txt
    │
    ├── ./run.sh
    │
    ├── ./runtime.txt
```

Even though my air_quality_api.py clearly exists it is giving me error:

```
 from air_quality_api import get_aqi
2019-08-03T06:21:48.084410+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'air_quality_api'
```

In my Procfile,

```
web: gunicorn AirQualityVisualizationApp.app:app
```

Since app is in app.py which is in AirQaulityVisualizationApp folder. Inside air_quality_api.py get_aqi function exists

In my app.py it looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, redirect, render_template
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func
import time

#my dependencies
from air_quality_api import get_aqi
from summarize_text import *



app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.start()

# ---------------------------------- Database setup -------------------------------- #
# setting up which database I will use
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', '') or 'mysql://root:Gksmf12#@localhost:3306/aqi_db'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

# # Creating database instance
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    """Return the homepage."""
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Can someone help? I've been trying to fix this for a while, cannot find anything that helps.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python version 3.7.3

Comment: Does `from .air_quality_api import get_aqi` work?