# I deployed my django web application to heroku and got "Application Error" message

Tags: python, django, heroku

I successfully deployed my Django web application to Heroku but got `Application Error` message. But, the web application works properly in local server.

[image: Error Message]

Here is my application log:

```
2020-08-04T03:32:15.540612+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:32:15.540612+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:32:15.857822+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:32:15.857822+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:32:46.278800+00:00 app[api]: Set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:32:46.278800+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.143606+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-perpendicular-61467) by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.143606+00:00 app[api]: Running release v4 commands by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.154813+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.154813+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-perpendicular-61467 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.474554+00:00 app[api]: Deploy e6fcf034 by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.474554+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:47.495253+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:34:53.033657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-08-04T03:34:55.434601+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-08-04T03:34:55.495150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-08-04T03:34:55.534079+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-04T03:34:55.536481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-04T03:34:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-04T03:35:01.196411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-08-04T03:35:03.730535+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-08-04T03:35:03.780569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-08-04T03:35:03.822189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-04T03:35:17.021136+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:35:17.021136+00:00 app[api]: Remove DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user rabby.jim999@gmail.com
2020-08-04T03:35:17.195336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-04T03:35:21.619153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-08-04T03:35:23.313884+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-08-04T03:35:23.354703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-08-04T03:35:23.400595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-04T03:35:26.401948+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-04T03:35:31.234524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-08-04T03:35:33.166497+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2020-08-04T03:35:33.216595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-08-04T03:35:33.251002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-04T03:35:43.283543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=itnewspaper.herokuapp.com request_id=65911b1e-d4c6-4
8a9-a170-3edcda5054b6 fwd="160.202.144.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-04T03:35:43.982143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=itnewspaper.herokuapp.com request_id=8b87
f553-20a6-4ba4-9c12-0da730fac6a7 fwd="160.202.144.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-04T03:49:41.311592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=itnewspaper.herokuapp.com request_id=acb47925-4576-4
355-8bc8-2a34c30e4c6c fwd="160.202.144.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-04T03:49:42.013324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=itnewspaper.herokuapp.com request_id=2ec8
9a3e-8803-423a-ad61-835ae4502388 fwd="160.202.144.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The steps I followed to deploy:

- `pipenv lock`
- `heroku login`
- `touch Procfile`
- `pip install gunicorn whitenoise django-heroku`
- `heroku create itnewspaper`
- `heroku git:remote -a itnewspaper`
- `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "Heroku config"`
- `git push heroku master`
- `heroku ps:scale web=1`
- `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`
- `heroku restart`
- `heroku open`

My `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --log-file -
```

My `Pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
asgiref = "3.2.10"
dj-database-url = "0.5.0"
Django = "3.0.8"
django-crispy-forms = "1.9.2"
django-heroku = "0.3.1"
gunicorn = "19.9.0"
psycopg2 = "2.8.5"
pytz = "2020.1"
sqlparse = "0.3.1"
whitenoise = "5.1.0"
```

Here is my `Pipfile.lock`:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "021bb8b6948e76168308f6200f1f2abc48a6a300c89ab19e93fcda0a5e298117"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "Django": "3.0.8",
            "asgiref": "3.2.10",
            "dj-database-url": "0.5.0",
            "django-crispy-forms": "1.9.2",
            "django-heroku": "0.3.1",
            "gunicorn": "19.9.0",
            "psycopg2": "2.8.5",
            "python_version": "3.7",
            "pytz": "2020.1",
            "sqlparse": "0.3.1",
            "whitenoise": "5.1.0"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "asgiref": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:7e51911ee147dd685c3c8b805c0ad0cb58d360987b56953878f8c06d2d1c6f1a",
                "sha256:9fc6fb5d39b8af147ba40765234fa822b39818b12cc80b35ad9b0cef3a476aed"
            ],
            "version": "==3.2.10"
        },
        "django": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:96fbe04e8ba0df289171e7f6970e0ff8b472bf4f909ed9e0e5beccbac7e1dbbe",
                "sha256:c22b4cd8e388f8219dc121f091e53a8701f9f5bca9aa132b5254263cab516215"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==3.0.9"
        },
        "pytz": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:a494d53b6d39c3c6e44c3bec237336e14305e4f29bbf800b599253057fbb79ed",
                "sha256:c35965d010ce31b23eeb663ed3cc8c906275d6be1a34393a1d73a41febf4a048"
            ],
            "version": "==2020.1"
        },
        "sqlparse": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:022fb9c87b524d1f7862b3037e541f68597a730a8843245c349fc93e1643dc4e",
                "sha256:e162203737712307dfe78860cc56c8da8a852ab2ee33750e33aeadf38d12c548"
            ],
            "version": "==0.3.1"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}
```

runtime.txt:

```
python-3.7.7
```

Here is my project [GitHub link](https://github.com/RabbyJim1/newspaper_project)

Comment: did you installed gunicorn?  `bash: gunicorn: command not found`

Comment: yes, i installed.

Comment: can you show your `Procfile`?

Comment: Procfile : `web: gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --logfile-file -` @Hisham___Pak

Comment: It should be `web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -` not `--logfile-file -`

Comment: I have done this correction with `web: gunicorn newspaper_project.wsgi --log-file -`. Now, the `bash: gunicorn: command not found` issue is solved. But, it still showing error. @Hisham___Pak

Comment: update the error and relevant files in your original post.

Comment: I have updated my post with the log. @Hisham___Pak

Comment: Please show your `requirements.txt` file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError :No module named 'requests'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272714/heroku-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests)

Comment: You're using two incompatible dependency managers. See the duplicate I just posted.

Comment: Please, review my post again. i have updated my post with new log and some required file. It shows `bash: gunicorn: command not found` error again. @Hisham___Pak

Comment: Thank you @Chris . I have seen you post and also done that you told in your ans. Move my `requirement.txt` to `Pipfile`, update `Pipfile.lock` and delete `requirement.txt` file. Then again i have pushed the application to heroku and try to open it. And it shows the same `Application Error`.

Comment: @MdGolamRabbyJim152-15-5551, if you've removed your `requirements.txt` its contents aren't relevant anymore, are they? Please [edit] your question and replace that information with the contents of your `Pipfile`. Also, please show the build output that you saw when you deployed your updated application.

Comment: Also, your GitHub link still shows the old content. We can't help you if you don't give us the right information...

Comment: I am sorry @Chris. I have updated my github and post contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting your dependencies in the wrong place. They belong in the `[packages]` section of your `Pipfile`, not the `[requires]` section.

**In general, you should rarely need to manually edit your `Pipfile` and you should *never* manually modify your `Pipfile.lock`.** Instead of adding things to your `Pipfile`, install them with `pipenv`, e.g. by running

```
pipenv install gunicorn
```

Pipenv will automatically update your `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` for you.

I suggest you do the following:

1. Delete `Pipfile.lock` locally
2. Delete your old virtualenv by running `pipenv --rm`
3. Move everything except `python_version = "3.7"` from `[requires]` to `[packages]`

   - Consider changing all versions to `"*"` so Pipenv is free to update versions
4. Run `pipenv install`
5. Make sure that the application works locally if you run it with `pipenv run`, or from `pipenv shell`
6. Commit the new `Pipfile.lock` that Pipenv generated
7. Deploy

Moving forward, I *strongly* urge you to install all dependencies by running `pipenv install` instead of modifying your `Pipfile` manually or using `pip`. This has the further benefit of making sure your local versions match what gets used on Heroku.

Oh, and you don't need `runtime.txt` if you are using Pipenv. The required Python version is already captured in your `Pipfile`.